# How to access friend functions correctly?

Tags: c++, class, methods, member, friend

I'm trying access a friend's method as defined the following. I have 4 files. Two header:

Header `a.h`:

```
#include "b.h"

class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
    void testStuff(int i);
};
```

Header `b.h`:

```
#include "a.h"

class A;

class B
{
    friend class A;

public:
    B();
    ~B();
    friend void doStuff(int i);
};
```

And two including some code, `a.cpp`:

```
#include "a.h"

void A::testStuff()
{
    B b {B()};
    b->doStuff(1);
}
```

`b.cpp`:

```
#include "b.h"

void B::doStuff(int i)
{
    m_stuff = i;
}
```

If I remove the keyword `friend` everything works fine. But if I declare `doStuff()` as a friend, I get the following error:

```
error: ‘class B’ has no member named ‘doStuff’
```

I tried following [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) tutorial. What do I miss?

Comment: `doStuff()` is a `friend` method of `B`, not a member.

Comment: Change `friend void doStuff(int i);` to `void doStuff(int i);`

Comment: @RakibulHasan exactly, what do i miss?

Comment: @drescherjm i know this works, but my question was how to get this to work? for example if I want to do this with a private method.

Comment: @RakibulHasan answered that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding regarding `friend` function is **wrong**. If you declare a function `friend` to another class, it means the `friend` function can access *private* members of that class, it does not mean the `friend` function becomes a *class member*.

Here `doStaff()` is `friend` to `B`, not a member of `B`. But you are using it on an object of `B`, hence compiler saying that it is not member of that class.  using `friend` gives `doStaff` permission to access `B`'s `private` members in it.

The tutorial you are following says it clearly. `duplicate()` method is a friend to `Rectangle`, hence it can access the `private` members `width` and `height`, but  `duplicate()`  is not used as a class method of `Rectangle`.

In summary, your question is wrong. You can access a `friend` function just like any *free* (non-class method) function. The question is how `friend` functions accesses the member of a class to which it is friend, and as said, it can access everything in that class, which is the motivation of having friend functions, namely to give access of *private* members of a class to a outsider.

Similarly a `friend` class can access everything of the class to which it is friend.

So for your problem, either you remove `friend` from `doStaff` to make it a member of `B`. But I guess your intention was to use `friend` method, in that case you can do the following:

```
void doStuff(B b, int i)
{
  b.m_stuff = i; // it is friend function of B, so can access m_staff
}
```

or you can make `doStaff()` member of `A` and then you can write

```
class A{
  //other members
  void doStaff(B& b, int i){ b.m_staff=i;}

void A::testStuff() {

  B b {B()};
  doStuff(b,1); //although u can just write "b.m_staff = 1;" right here
}
```

Comment: Now I got it. I thought I can use the friend's private methods, but accessing it's members is even more comfortable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There would be no point to declare methods in your own class as "friend". Therefore, a friend declaration like

```
friend void doStuff(int i);
```

inside class B doesn't actually declare a member function of class B (it's family, you don't need to make it a friend), it declares a global function named doStuff. You could write

```
friend void A::doStuff(int i);
```

which means "If there is a class named A somewhere, and it has a member named doStuff with an int parameter, then that member function is a friend". What you wrote was "if there is a global function doStuff (int i) somewhere, then that function is a friend".

So you haven't declared B:doStuff (int i) in your class, and implementing the function very sensibly gives an error.

And if you want A::testStuff() to be allowed to call doStuff, you should add in class B:

```
friend void A::testStuff ();
```

Comment: +1 definitely, this is a global friend function in the example.

Answer (score 1):

You declared doStuff() as a **member** of class B, when you did "void B::doStuff(int i)", but
the *friend* keyword applies to **non-member** functions. It's basically there to make it so that a function that is not a member of a class can access that class's private members.

BTW, B has class A declared as a *friend*, which means a function that you declare in A can access private members in class B.

As you can see, there's a difference between declaring friend classes and friend functions.